# How to read or write 64-bit numbers in С?

Tags: c, input, 64-bit, long-long

Can I take 64 bit numbers input in C with %lld?

If not how to?
Please give an example when you answer.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using`%lld`?  What happened when you did?  What problems did you have?

Comment: It was said in the problem not to use %lld. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can read integers of `long long` with `%lld` specifier via `scanf()` if your compiler and standard library supports that, but it is not guaranteed to be 64bit. (`long long` can store at least numbers between `-9223372036854775807` (`-(2**63 - 1)`) and `+9223372036854775807` (`2**63 - 1`) (both inclusive), so it should be at least 64bit)

You can use `int64_t` type and `"%" SCNd64` format specifier from `inttypes.h` if it is supported in your environment. `int64_t` is a signed integer type with exactly 64bit.
You can use `uint64_t` type and `"%" SCNu64` format specifier for unsigned 64-bit integer.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    int64_t num;
    if (scanf("%" SCNd64, &num) != 1) { /* read 64-bit number */
        puts("read error");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%" PRId64 "\n", num); /* print the number read */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why you used void in int main ( void) ? I am new to programming and donot know about that.

Comment: Because it it defined so in the standard and I don't use arguments  here. [What should main() return in C and C++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)